# Relative position of Div in another Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position

How do I get the position of a Div relatively to its parent Div? Using `.position()` and `.offset()` always gives me its position to the document.

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="frame">
   <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS:**

Let's assume `frame` is centered with `margin: auto;` and `width: 1024px`.

`inner` has `left: 300px;`, `top: 200px` and `position: relative;`.

**What I want:**

A nice function for getting `inners`'s position data `300` and `200` (e.g. without `px` when using `.css('left')` etc.

Is there anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give the parent a "position" of "relative", then using `.position()` should be its position inside of the parent.

Using `.offset` actually should **always** give you its position based off the `document`, while using `.position` gives you its "position" based off its first parent whose "position" is not "static" (default).

Here's examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2VNx/

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2VNx/1/

The first example uses `<br />` to add space at the top of the container, while the second example uses `padding-top` to add space at the top of the container. Both return a value greater than `0` for the child's `top` position.

The only problem is that `position` does not account for the child's margins, padding, and borders when calculating its position. This is because all of those are part of the element, so even though you may not visually see them, they wouldn't be included in the element's position calculation. So of course, depending on exactly what part of the element you want to see its position of, you need to add that to the result of `.position`. Some people want the "position" to return to top-left position of the border, which would mean adding the margin. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2VNx/2/

Comment: Alright I see, weird. I think I made a mistake. It works now. How do I get the relative position of a click made to inside the id `frame`?

Comment: @Indianer I'm not sure what you mean by "relative position of click made to inside the id `frame`". Do you mean where the actual `click` occurred, relative to the `frame` element?

Comment: Yes like this `$("#frame").click(function(oEvent) { $(this).position(); });` The coord of the mouse click inside the `frame`

Comment: That is what I use right now. But I want to be independent of the document `evt.pageY|X`, because if `frame` is centered and people have different browser window sizes, this would lead to wrong calculations, since the margin left would be different in each browser.

Comment: @Indianer I'm not sure I follow. If you want to get the mouse's position, you have to use `evt.pageX|Y` - and it will always return the position based on the `document`. If you want to get the mouse's position inside of another element, you have to subtract the element's `offset` height/width. The calculation shouldn't ever be wrong - what `offset` returns is exactly what you need. No matter at what point you click the element, its `offset` will be found dynamically (in case the browser window was resize or scrolled) and then figured out based on the mouse position overall.

Comment: @Indianer I'd like to help more - if you can provide a fiddle or something where it isn't working as you'd like, I'll look at it.

Comment: Ok I if something comes up I will write again. Thank you.